# Differ by vs Differ in

Tags: differences

Please tell me which sentence is written the right way:

X differs from Y in having vertebral folds.
X differs from Y by having vertebral folds.

I already read differ by is only used when it refers to values or sizes (is it true?), but I feel that in the case of this sentence *differ by* express better the idea that Y do not have folds. English is not my native language, so it can be just bad intuition. Could someone please confirm it?

Comment: _differ by_ can definitely be used here and sounds better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **in** *preposition*
>   4.1 Indicating the quality or aspect with respect to which a judgment is made.
>   ‘no discernible difference in quality’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/in)
>
> **by** *preposition*
>   3 Indicating the amount or size of a margin.
>   ‘the shot missed her by miles’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/by)

When things differ **in** something, that something is usually a common category of the things that are different. Here's an example:

- These hand-made articles differ in quality.
  [- manythings.org](http://www.manythings.org/sentences/words/differ/1.html)

Differ **by** is sometime used in a similar fashion:

- Marriage customs differ by country
  [- manythings.org](http://www.manythings.org/sentences/words/differ/1.html)

Where a specific 'trait' (not just the category) is specified, it carries the implication that there is a main 'thing' that is compared to another, and that it is the main 'thing' that has the trait but the other doesn't. Here's an example (emphasis, mine):

- The immature specimens of *W. oregonensis* (Anderson) show considerable resemblance to small specimens of *Homosomites stantoni* (McLellan), as figured by Imlay (1956, pl.120, figs. 1-5) but **differ by** having weaker primary ribs that fade earlier, ....

  > [- Geological Survey Professional Paper](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=x0BSAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA205&dq=%22differ%20by%20having%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLg9zLsJLXAhUJfrwKHYspA-4Q6AEINTAC#v=onepage&q=%22differ%20by%20having%22&f=false)

Here, the implication is that the *immature specimens* have the weaker primary ribs etc.

Note that *by* can also idiomatically refer to the degree of difference:

- Relative to the IIa items, the IIb items differ by one letter, the Ilc items by two letters, and the III items by one letter.
  [- The Psychology of Associative Learning](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=RuBO56fHjT0C&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=%22differ%20by%20one%20letter%22&source=bl&ots=R-QMyAdd7h&sig=ii7zPDrxnVW9BNJS_sXwPXuWWGc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWp9eMr5LXAhVIf7wKHUIrBd4Q6AEIVjAI#v=onepage&q=%22differ%20by%20one%20letter%22&f=false)

In your case, saying "X differs from Y in having vertebral folds" has the sense that *having vertebral folds* is the category of interest but doesn't specify the specifics of that difference. X might have them and Y might not, or Y might have them and X might not. On the other hand, "X differs from Y by having vertebral folds" has the sense that X has them while Y doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the first sentence as  " X differs from Y in that it has vertebral folds (whereas Y does not)."  [parenthetical clause optional] .

In general,  write  "X differs [from Y] in [the number of / the color of / other distinguishing characteristic]."   I'm not sure I like using "differ...by..." at all, but I would limit it to situations in which X is performing an *action* rather than exhibiting a trait different from Y.

I'm open to corrections here.